# ImageView with vector drawable size

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm using a vector drawable and I want my image view with a background of 40dp and the image of 24dp.
I've got this layout now:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_image"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>
```

The problem is that the image is scaled and fills all 40dp even if in the vector drawable I've got:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
```

The drawable circle is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <size
        android:width="40dp"
        android:height="40dp"/>
</shape>
```

How can I fix the layout? Do I need to convert the vector into png?

Comment: this is because `ImageView` by default scales the input `Drawable` with `ScaleType.FIT_CENTER`, read `ImageView.ScaleType` documentation for other values

Comment: @pskink Thanks, solved using scale center

Comment: good: BTW you could use a `LayerDrawable` with 2 layers (circle & vector) and pass it to `View#setBackground`, no need for an `ImageView`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem using `android:scaleType` with the value `center`.